# Why render_component is deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why `render_component` is deprecated in Rails > 2. What is the rational behind that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render_component` is very slow and it has special case usage which often can be replaced by simple partial.

As the [README](http://github.com/rails/render_component) for the render_component says:

> Components should be used with care. They're significantly slower than simply splitting reusable parts into partials and
>   conceptually more complicated. Don't use components as a way of separating concerns inside a single application.
>
> Instead, reserve components to those rare cases where you truly have reusable view and controller elements that can be employed across many applications at once.
>
> So to repeat: Components are a special-purpose approach that can often be replaced with better use of partials and 
>   filters.